# How to downgrade Ubuntu from version 22.04 to 20.04?

Tags: 22.04

I want to downgrade my ubuntu version 22.04 to 20.04. I'm facing lot of issues since I upgraded the system to 22.04 like,

1. System is hanging sometimes
2. Battery is draining too fast.
3. Lock screen delay

Comment: There's no downgrade path, only reinstallation.

Comment: How are we to know what backup strategy you're using.  Ubuntu [*release-upgrade* tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) will upgrade you to a later release; downgrading is done via whatever backup strategy you put in place.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you mean I have to reinstall 20.04?

Comment: and why is this tagged 20.10?  @Satya yes that is what he means. I would suggest a re-install of 22.04 though if you going to re-install. 1 and 2 might be due to the upgrade. 3 is a feature that needs fixing (wayland + open source driver are the issue): it will disappear when you use the 3rd party driver if you have nvidia or when using xorg instead of wayland

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah! I'm sorry. Okay I'll try re-installing. Thanks!

Comment: Better to troubleshoot the problems you have now, even backup personal files and install from scratch just to rule out some rare problem with the release upgrade. But if you really want 20.04 then yes, you'll have to install it.

Comment: Got it @ChanganAuto. Thanks! I'll try to fix the issues.

Comment: If you're talking about a desktop system (*you didn't specify if talking about desktop or server, mentioning only release details*) you can re-install the same release, or a different release without losing your user files, and having the *manually installed* packages (ie. those you added to your system) automatically re-install IF they're available for the new release in Ubuntu repositories (ie. not intended for 3rd party).  I regularly perform this in QA; though I always perform additional checks (per package) before doing it on systems I value.